# What are the possible causes of a process being automatically suspended?

Tags: bash, zsh

```bash
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
brandon@Air portal % fg
[1]  + 81104 continued  rails server --port=3007
[1]  + 81104 suspended (signal)  rails server --port=3007
```

I am not hitting <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>—the process is getting suspended as soon as I bring it back into the foreground.  I have run out of ideas.  What are possible causes of this?

Comment: Are you doing this in both shells (tagged bash and zsh), or is your question focused on the behavior of your primary shell?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Since this is intermittent behavior I can't easily verify that it behaves exactly the same in Zsh and Bash, but I have seen very similar behavior (which I believe is related to the example I gave here, but which I can't prove is related without finding the underlying cause) in both Bash and Zsh, so _as far as I know_ this is relevent to both shells, and changing the shell won't prevent the problem.  The example given occurred in Zsh.

Answer (score 2):

A process can be suspended if something sends it the `SIGTSTP` signal. That's what Ctrl-Z does, but the signal has the same effect.

Some interactive applications themselves call `raise(SIGTSTP)` to suspend themselves. This is done by programs which put the terminal into a raw mode (e.g. to implement editing). For instance, when you hit Ctrl-Z in a text editor like Vim, it's not the TTY driver that intercepts the Ctrl-Z to send the `SIGTSTP` signal. That is disabled because the TTY is in raw mode. The editor receives Ctrl-Z which it interprets as a suspend command. Part of that command's action is to send the `SIGTSTP` signal to the process itself.

It's unlikely that something which looks like a background server application would be doing anything of this sort, though. The signal could come from any process which has permissions.

If the process itself is sending itself the signal, running strace on it from another terminal window could reveal that.

```
strace -p 81104
```

Then examine what system calls lead up to the point where it suspends again.

Comment: I'm using iTerm (as well as tmux), and I believe there are circumstances where iTerm asks for permission to use raw mode (perhaps when copying text).  But I've never paid close attention to that.  If I can prevent raw mode, would I possibly prevent the suspension of the process?